RxJS: shareReplay's `refCount: false` in a scoped service: Will it complete and be garbage collected on service destroy?
Goal:
I'd like to cache an observable's data for all current and future subscribers even if there are currently no subscribers:
shareReplay({refCount: false, bufferSize: 1})
The observable is declared inside a non-root-provided service so it will be destroyed together with its providing component.
Questions:

What will happen to the observable when the component + service + all subscribers are destroyed?

Will it complete and be ready to be garbage collected?
Or will the refCount: false force the Observable and therefore the surrounding context (i.e. service) to be kept somewhere in memory which would lead to a memory leak?


Do I need to provide some destroy helper like takeUntilDestroyed() in this case at the end of the observable pipe after the shareReplay?


Thoughts:
As far as I know

memory leaks are created when a subscription is still active on an observable outside of the current context that should be destroyed

if the observable and its subcription live within the same context as the destroyed context no leak should appear


In the case of this scoped service I had guessed that case 2 would be applicable and the internal subscription of refCount:false would be destroyed together with the surrounding context, but I'm not sure.

shareplay' has nothing to do with whether you subscribe or not. Shareplay allows a cold observable to be made hot, meaning that future subscribers will receive the last value (in case of refCount: false, bufferSize: 1)  emitted by the stream at the time of the first subscription.
No memory leaks append when you dont unsubscribe a subscription.

Yes, you need to provide some destroy helper. This bug (or expected behavior?) is still present.

@Tim I have to disagree. Please see the doc on the shareReplay's source:
https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/packages/rxjs/src/internal/operators/shareReplay.ts
shareReplay does indeed build up an inner subscription itself that is held active in the connected ReplaySubject as soon as the first subscriber appears. With refCount: false this subscription will then even last when no subscriber is active anymore.

You will have to use takeUntilDestroyed or a similar approach in your service to make sure that everything was correctly cleaned up.
I created a simple application that reproduces your use case: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/vigilant-babycat-f7kt2p
If you open DevTools and comment lines 70-71 in test.service.ts you will see that your subscriptions are not automatically cleaned up if refCount: false. That's because shareReplay is a bit tricky, eventually you end up with at least two subscriptions: the first subscription is inside share (you can't manually unsubscribe from it), the rest are from your code to the shareReplay's internal ReplaySubject (source code).
FYI, first is needed to simulate an HTTP-response from a backend server.

Your link to codesandbox seems to be the wrong one.

@manuelkue my bad. now should be correct

Thanks for the answer and the code examples. It's disturbing this leak is kind of unknown (at least in our company where we use shareReplay alot).
Maybe it's some edge case because of such pipes usually used in root-provided services. refCount: true should be the preferred one in scoped services and components I guess

@manuelkue I found a video that explains why how sharReplay works: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVKAzhlqTx8

Yes, that describes the problem quite nicely
